# Azure VM Provisioning for 24+ hours

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, windows-server

I have a Windows VM on Azure that has been "Provisioning" for more than 24 hours. We have used this VM before and I need to access it, but I cannot do anything with it because it is stuck. Has anyone had this problem? How can I fix it without having to reconfigure the machine?

Comment: Sounds like this should be addressed to Microsoft's Support...

Comment: @Liel I agree. Unfortunately, I can only get billing support unless I purchase a support plan. I may end up doing that, but it seems ridiculous to pay for support because the service we're already paying for is not functioning. I'm trying the community approach first. We'll see if it pays off.

Comment: Delete and create again if you can.